# Change html elemts style from Controllers ActionResult in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making an if check in the controller

```
if(validDate<DateTime.Now)
{
   //TODO
}
```

And what I want to do is to hide a specific button in my view if this statement is true, otherwise show it. I am also using jquery in front end.
Can someone help me to manipulate the html element, the button, from the controller, example add a style class or something?
In this case I need to make the changes from the controller and not from the jquery, but I can use the jquery after if needed.

Comment: It's easy and one of the core concepts of ASP.NET MVC. I'd highly encourage you to read more documentation, e.g: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3 (once you have a ViewModel, it's easy to set a `bool` property like `IsDateValid` to `true` or `false` and make the check in the View whether to display a button or not

Comment: can you please provide me an example answer for my case? I know it's very basic but ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use models (aka as ViewModel), @thomashaid already gave you a comment with a useful article: [Views And ViewModels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3).

Create a class in the "Models" folder of your MVC Project. Like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool ShowButton { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your controller, create an object of your `ViewModel` class and assign the corresponding value to the `ShowButton` property. Then pass the ViewModel to the returning view:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var myViewmodel = new MyViewModel();´

    if(validDate < DateTime.Now)
    {
        myViewModel.ShowButton = true;
    }

    return View(myViewModel);
}
```

Finally, use razor syntax in your view to manipulate the HTML code that will be returned to the client:

```
@model MyViewModel

@if (Model.ShowButton)
{
    <Button>now you see me</Button>
}
```